# Why does it cause Access Violation when moving the mouse cursor in and out for many times?

Tags: c++, mfc

There are 5 polygonal areas in the window. If the user's mouse moves over one of the polygon, it shows the Message Box.

The code is like below:

```
void OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point){
    CPoint pt[5][6];

    //The points of polygon0 
    pt[0][0].x = 18;
    pt[0][0].y = 639;
    pt[0][1].x = -4;
    pt[0][1].y = 688;
    pt[0][2].x = 17;
    pt[0][2].y = 707;
    pt[0][3].x = 42;
    pt[0][3].y = 683;
    pt[0][4].x = 47;
    pt[0][4].y = 637;
    pt[0][5].x = 80;
    pt[0][5].y = 638;

    //The points of polygon1
    pt[1][0].x = 47;
    pt[1][0].y = 637;
    pt[1][1].x = 42;
    pt[1][1].y = 683;
    pt[1][2].x = 17;
    pt[1][2].y = 707;
    pt[1][3].x = 56;
    pt[1][3].y = 714;
    pt[1][4].x = 89;
    pt[1][4].y = 674;
    pt[1][5].x = 80;
    pt[1][5].y = 638;

    //The points of polygon2
    pt[2][0].x = 80;
    pt[2][0].y = 638;
    pt[2][1].x = 89;
    pt[2][1].y = 674;
    pt[2][2].x = 56;
    pt[2][2].y = 714;
    pt[2][3].x = 101;
    pt[2][3].y = 713;
    pt[2][4].x = 126;
    pt[2][4].y = 675;
    pt[2][5].x = 111;
    pt[2][5].y = 637;

    //The points of polygon3
    pt[3][0].x = 111;
    pt[3][0].y = 637;
    pt[3][1].x = 126;
    pt[3][1].y = 675;
    pt[3][2].x = 101;
    pt[3][2].y = 713;
    pt[3][3].x = 143;
    pt[3][3].y = 713;
    pt[3][4].x = 166;
    pt[3][4].y = 676;
    pt[3][5].x = 166;
    pt[3][5].y = 638;

    //The points of polygon4
    pt[4][0].x = 166;
    pt[4][0].y = 638;
    pt[4][1].x = 166;
    pt[4][1].y = 676;
    pt[4][2].x = 143;
    pt[4][2].y = 713;
    pt[4][3].x = 173;
    pt[4][3].y = 713;
    pt[4][4].x = 206;
    pt[4][4].y = 679;
    pt[4][5].x = 188;
    pt[4][5].y = 638;

    HRGN hrgn[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        hrgn[i] = CreatePolygonRgn(pt[i], 6, ALTERNATE);

    if(PtInRegion(hrgn[0], point.x, point.y)){
        //Your mouse is moving over polygon0
        MessageBox(L"Your mouse is moving over polygon0");
    }else if(PtInRegion(hrgn[1], point.x, point.y)){
        //Your mouse is moving over polygon1
        MessageBox(L"Your mouse is moving over polygon1");
    }else if(PtInRegion(hrgn[2], point.x, point.y)){
        //Your mouse is moving over polygon2
        MessageBox(L"Your mouse is moving over polygon2");
    }else if(PtInRegion(hrgn[3], point.x, point.y)){
        //Your mouse is moving over polygon3
        MessageBox(L"Your mouse is moving over polygon3");
    }else if(PtInRegion(hrgn[4], point.x, point.y)){
        //Your mouse is moving over polygon4
        MessageBox(L"Your mouse is moving over polygon4");
    }else{
        //Other events...
    }

    DeleteObject(pt);
    DeleteObject(hrgn);
}
```

It seems like there's no problem about the code. But if I try to move the mouse cursor in and out the polygons for many many times, it may cause an Access Violation problem (AV problem). So what causes the AV problem? Is there any better way to deal with it?

Comment: Run in a debugger to catch the crash in action, and locate where in your code it happens.

Comment: On an unrelated note, if the polygons are fixed and will never change, you should probably make `pt` a `static const` variable, and initialize it when you define the variable. The code will be shorter, and the compiler will emit the data so there's no run-time overhead from the initialization.

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Comment: No error checking => kaboom.  Calling DeleteObject() to release the polygons is not optional, the OS pulls the plug after you created ten thousand of them.

Comment: @Hans Passant Where should I call the `DeleteObject()`? It seems like those 5 polygons are all "necessary" at any time...

Comment: They are no longer necessary after you no longer call PtInRegion().  Since you create them again when the mouse moves again.

Comment: @Hans Passant I have done it your way, but it still caused the AV problem...

Comment: If you're still having the same problem, edit the code in the question and show where you put the `DeleteObject`. @HansPassant is absolutely correct.

Comment: I have edited the code just now.

Comment: No, your edit is wrong. `DeleteObject(hrgn)` would be used to delete a single region. You have an array of 5 regions. You have to call `DeleteObject` in a loop, each time deleting one of the 5 regions.

Comment: Oh, I see... Thanks

Comment: Cody Gray is right.  Also, you should not be calling `DeleteObject(pt)`.  I can't believe that even compiled.  The points are just an array that lives on the stack.  They'll go out of scope automatically.  You need to call DeleteObject on HRGNs and most other handle-based GDI objects, but not on plain old classes/structs (like CPoint or POINT).

Comment: Run Task Manager and add the column "GDI objects". Move the mouse in and out of your window. Look to the Task Manager and then you will understand why you need to `DeleteObject`. Free tip from me: Windows has a limit of 9999 GDI objects per running executable.

Comment: In addition of @Someprogrammerdude's first comment: Put several tracepoints in your method; run the app in **Debug** configuration and look to the Output Window, and progressively narrow down to get what is the statement before bang happens.

Comment: As @AdrianMcCarthy points out, calling `DeleteObject` on the `CPoint` array is an error. If it compiles, it means, that you haven't defined the `STRICT` preprocessor symbol. It's job is to enable stricter type checking on USER/GDI handle types. If it isn't defined, all handles are treated as `void*`, and any pointer (including the array that decays into a pointer to its first element) can be implicitly converted to a `void*`. With that out of the way, you really shouldn't be using MFC. It requires that you know C++ and the Windows API. It looks like you are lacking in both departments.